# How can primitive values have properties in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, object

I have a little misunderstanding in JavaScript string type.

According to *JavaScript: The Definitive Guide*, by David Flanagan,

> Any JavaScript value that is not a number, a string, a boolean, or
>   `null` or `undefined` is an object. An object (that is, a member of the
>   type *object*) is a collection of *properties* where each property has a
>   name and a value

Let's take an example:

```js
var t = "some text";
t.length // give me the length of t
```

How is it possible? I know that JavaScript strings are primitive values (like numbers), so how is it possible for a primitive value to have a property (like object)?

Comment: `t.length` under the hood does something like `Object(t).length`, where `Object(t)` is a [string object](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.18) (not to be confused with a primitive [string value](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.16)).

Comment: Everything in Javascript has a "standard built-in objects", because of it you have a length function in the string object. take a look https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects